# New basecamp api tells me there's no basecamp account at this address

Tags: api, basecamp

I'm new to basecamp api, and while trying out the simplest example:

```
curl -u user:pass -H 'User-Agent: MyApp (yourname@example.com)' https://basecamp.com/999999999/api/v1/projects.json
```

I got the error says:

```
There's no Basecamp account at this address. Sign in to Launchpad to see your accounts.
```

I replaced the user with my basecamp email address, and the pass as the password.Am I putting something wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to specify **user-agent** either your **email address** or app name, in my opinion input your email address and mention your basecamp account id (after login in basecamp account, id shows on **url** in number form )

```
example :
curl -u xyz@example.com:xxxxxx -H 'User-Agent: xyz@example.com' https://basecamp.com/1213136/api/v1/projects.json
```

And finally you get your json!!

Comment: where does the number 1213136 come from? is that your user id#?

Comment: @Damon: This is basecamp account id, as you can see this unique id in url after login in basecamp account

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and was able to get the solution.
Found out that i've been using the wrong Basecamp account id.

I've have created an account in Basecamp 3 (https://basecamp.com) and been using the generated account id in my requests, but I keep getting the said error message.

You just need to create an account in Basecamp 2 (https://billing.37signals.com/bcx/trial/signup) and use the generated account id instead.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and was able to get the solution. Found out that i've been using the wrong Basecamp account id.

I've have created an account in Basecamp 3 (https://basecamp.com) and been using the generated account id in my requests, but I keep getting the said error message.

You just need to create an account in Basecamp 2 (https://billing.37signals.com/bcx/trial/signup) and use the generated account id instead.